# T4 Template Transformation Service

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-4.0, code-generation, t4

We currently have an asp.net website that we use to generate html emails. Basically we pass in some parameters and it spits out an html page that we then send in an email. Essentially ASP.NET is our templating engine. I was looking to for a different way of doing this and I was thinking about using T4 templates instead. Is there a way to generate templates on the fly with T4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. See the following links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx

There is a command-line utility: `TextTransform.exe`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx

Comment: Runtime templates (the second link above) are definitely the way to go for this application of T4.